# Remove duplicate list items recieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, html-lists

I have some issues with a list that needs to be displayed in a page.

This is what currently shows up on the page.

**Students**

- Student 3 
  01-02-2016 from 08:30 to 14:30
- Student 1
  01-06-2016 from 10:30 to 15:30
- Student 1
  01-08-2016 from 05:30 to 16:30
- Student 3
  03-05-2016 from 08:30 to 10:30
- Student 2
  01-1-2016 from 13:30 to 18:30
- Student 1
  01-02-2016 from 16:30 to 20:30

It should look like: 
**Students**

- Student 1
  01-02-2016 from 16:30 to 20:30 
  01-06-2016 from 10:30 to 15:30 
  01-08-2016 from 05:30 to 16:30
- Student 2
  01-1-2016 from 13:30 to 18:30
- Student 3
  01-02-2016 from 08:30 to 14:30 
  03-05-2016 from 08:30 to 10:30

This information comes from the database:

```
<div id="preferences">
    <h2>Leerlingen</h2>
    <?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT leerlingen.firstname, leerlingen.lastname, 
             voorkeuren.start, voorkeuren.end, voorkeuren.title FROM 
             leerlingen JOIN voorkeuren ON leerlingen.uid=voorkeuren.title";

    $result2 = $db->query($sql2);

    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

      ?>
        <ul>
            <li><h4><?= $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'];?></h4></li>
            <?= "Van " .  date('j-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row['start'])) . " tot " . date('H:i', strtotime($row['end'])) ?>
        </ul>

      <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I tried to solve it using a array unique for the student name but then the dates below the students are all the same.

Comment: Why dont you are using group by student name?

Comment: @sAcH - probably because OP still requires all the recors, it's just the display formatting that needs changing

Comment: Apply an order by clause to your SQL query; then check in your display loop and only display student name if different to the previous student name

Comment: $sql2 = "SELECT leerlingen.firstname, leerlingen.lastname, voorkeuren.start, voorkeuren.end, voorkeuren.title
FROM leerlingen
JOIN voorkeuren
ON leerlingen.uid=voorkeuren.title ORDER BY leerlingen.firstname ";

Comment: order by will just order the data not merge same student which is retrieving more than once ?? @MarkBaker

Comment: Looks like you'll need to also order by the start/date, after the name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I just added: 'ORDER BY leerlingen.lastname ASC, voorkeuren.start ASC' It just doesnt merge them but this seems better then before

Comment: Changing the query won't merge them; you need to do that in your display loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build an array and then traverse it and display the html

```
$sql2 = "SELECT leerlingen.firstname, leerlingen.lastname, voorkeuren.start, voorkeuren.end, voorkeuren.title
FROM leerlingen
JOIN voorkeuren
ON leerlingen.uid=voorkeuren.title group by leerlingen.firstname";

$studentArr = [];

while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $studentName = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
    if(!array_key_exists($studentName,$studentArr))
        $studentArr[] = $studentName;
     $studentArr[$studentName][] = $row['start'];
     $studentArr[$studentName][] = $row['end'];
}

foreach($studentArr as $key => $val){
    //your html code here
}
```

Comment: ORDER BY, not GROUP BY.

Comment: Why not group by ?

Comment: @sAcH thanks but not there yet.. When i use: <?= $val .  '<br>'  ?> for testing it shows:  Test Account

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\lansingerland\instructeurs\irooster.php on line 47
Array

Can you also help me solving this? thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry: Please clarify... Before giving negative marks think twice...Or else correct me if anything wrong

Comment: @OrlandoDuivestein: Have you tried by printing $studentArr before traversing it?

Comment: @OwaisAslam because there's no aggregation here. The OP simply wants to arrange the array according to user and date. This can be done either within the query (by means or an ORDER BY clause) or in PHP directly, using an assortment of array manipulation functions.

Comment: @sAcH I tried it by echo $studentName . "<BR>";
    echo $studentArr[$studentName][0] . " - " . $studentArr[$studentName][1];
    echo "<BR><BR>"; but this only echos the same line

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the same table and have a primary key, then try using the following query: (For single table)

**Updated:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.id = (SELECT t2.id
FROM distance t2 WHERE t2.fromid = t.fromid
GROUP BY t2.id LIMIT 1)
THEN t.id
ELSE '' END AS FromId, t.toid, t.id, t.distance
FROM distance t
```

**Note:** The above query returns only distinct names or id and if it has multiple tables, then you have to use `JOIN`. That's it. Firstly try using it in a single table.

**Output:**

[image: prevent_duplicate]

Comment: The question appears (at least in part) to be about mysql

Comment: Updated @Strawberry for MySQL.

Comment: This is terrible :-(

Comment: I would expect any other better solution. No worries @Strawberry. Do you have any one?